# Storing ruby on rails objects retrieved from sql database into javascript objects

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, ruby-on-rails

So I have an assets table in my sql database and I am accessing them in my view like so:

```
  <% @step.assets.each do |asset| %>
    <td><%= asset.name%></td>
    <td><%= asset.width%></td>
    <td><%= asset.height%></td>
    <td><%= asset.x%></td>
    <td><%= asset.y%></td>
  <% end -%>
```

And as you can see displaying the different attributes inside a table for the user to see.

The thing that I want to do now is actually save those asset attributes in javascript objects
so that I can manipulate them in the ui. I tried something like:

```
    var obj = <%= @step.asset.name%>;
```

But that didn't work and I have searched around for a couple hours now looking for a solution. I have a ton of experience with javascript but Ruby on Rails is still pretty new to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something simple you can use [to_json](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json), like in the following:

```
var asset = <%= raw @step.asset.to_json %>
```

By the way, it's not a very maintainable solution. So you could use a lightweight framework like spinejs.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work I think my problem is I am not sure where I should be doing this. I put it inside of a script tag in the view but it gives me an empty function because of the ruby. and even though I know @step is not nil if I it seems to think that it is no matter what I do.

Comment: It think you would take one of your view files that has the `@step` object in it and then add the javascript there.  So as in `<script type='text/javascript'>` ... `var asset = <%= @step.asset.to_json %>;`  ... `</script>`.